# Function taking an array and a function on an element array

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm starting to learn Scala and while reading Scala for the Impatient, got to the following solution to one of the exercises:

```
//No function
def positivesThenZerosAndNegatives(values: Array[Int]) = {
    Array.concat(for (value <- values if value > 0) yield value,
        for (value <- values if value == 0) yield value,
        for (value <- values if value < 0) yield value)
}
```

But now I was trying to pass as param the function that applies the filter on each comprehensive for:

```
//Trying to use a function (filter)
def positivesThenZerosAndNegatives2(values: Array[Int]) = {
    Array.concat(filter(values, _ > 0), filter(values, _ == 0), filter(values, _ < 0))
}

def filter[T: Int](values: Array[T], f: (T) => Boolean) = {
    for (value <- values if f(value)) yield value
}
```

I haven't found the right way to refer to an element array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either writer your `filter` method as following:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def filter[T: ClassTag](values: Array[T], f: T => Boolean): Array[T] = {
  for(value <- values; if f(value)) yield value
}
```

or as this:

```
def filter(values: Array[Int], f: Int => Boolean): Array[Int] = {
  for(value <- values; if f(value)) yield value
}
```

Anyway, you can simply re-write your method `positivesThenZerosAndNegatives` like this:

```
scala> def positivesThenZerosAndNegatives(values: Array[Int]) = {
     |   values.filter(0 <) ++ values.filter(0 ==) ++ values.filter(0 >)
     | }
```